# Visualize increase/decrease of value based on cell above

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working on a very big data set of visitor numbers to a location. I wish to find a way to mark increase or decrease either by arrows or color to quickly analyse the entire data set. Usually I would be using graphs, but there are to many factors now so the graph is unreadable.

The result in this video is a good example of the result I want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFU5ZlHUdH0

The problem with that method is that my numbers are in total values, with no + or - sign used, and manually adding - isn't really an option in a set this big.

Is there any way to make color changes in a cell based on the cell above when to total value is lower or higher?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? If it is a later version, have you looked at using one of the icon sets in conditional formatting?

Comment: I tried, but the icons did not follow the wanted convention by their own design. I will be trying Chris2015's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional formatting using a formula. You apply the formatting (color etc.) based on the difference between the two cells. Say, you had data in cells `A1:A10` you would -

1. Highlight `A2:A10` (start in A2)
2. Go to Home
3. Go to Conditional Formatting
4. Go to New Rule
5. Use a formula to determine which cells to format. In the formula bar. Enter `=(A2-A1)<0`.
6. Click Format and decide what type of formatting you'd like (change font, fill etc.).
7. Click Ok.

The result should be that each cell is formatted `IF` the current cell decreases relative to the preceding cell.

Comment: How is the formula for that? I really don't know anything on this subject and have not been able to make sense out of what I have read about it.

Comment: Welcome to Super user. Just a couple pointers to improve your answer. Please take a minute to format your answer. For instance, use code formatting for your formulas and lists for the steps taken to follow your solution. As is, it is just a bunch of text and hard to read.  If you need some help, read [How do I write a good answer?](http://www.superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Worked perfectly.Thank you for such a clear explanation!